# What can we say about the kernel of diagonalizable operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. And $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator. Assume that there exists an orthonormal basis of $V$ so the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is diagonalizable matrix.

> that Question: Can we say $\text{null} T = \text{null} T^2$?  (We also assume  that the matrix of $T^2=T\circ T$ is also diagonalizable)

Comment: Whether a matrix (or a linear transformation for that matter) is diagonalisable or not is entirely independent of what basis we choose. Being "diagonal", on the other hand, is very dependent on basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a matrix such that $D=P^{-1}TP$ is diagonal. Then
$$Dx=0\Leftrightarrow PDx=TPx=0,$$
and thus $\ker( D)=P(\ker (T))$. Since moreover $D^2=P^{-1}T^2P$, we also have $\ker( D^2)=P(\ker (T^2))$.

Now since $D$ is diagonal, $\ker(D)=\ker(D^2)$, and thus $\ker(T)=\ker(T^2)$.